# Rails 4.2: Nested form that selects 2 objects from a different model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, model-view-controller, nested-forms

I am currently building a tricky form. I am still a fairly young Rails developer so half the battle is grasping how to go about this.

I need to build a form that launches a Campaign. This Campaign will need to be named and commented. It also needs to choose a .zip file form a pre-populated dropdown box. Under that will be the ability to choose one of 5 .pdf files via a check box. Zip files and pdf files are a part of the same model `Upload`.

So far my Campaign model...

**models/campaign.rb**

```
class Campaign < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :uploads

    validates :name, presence: true,
                    uniqueness: true

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :uploads
end
```

The Uploads model represents the table that holds zip and pdf files..

**models/uploads.rb**

```
class Upload < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_one :campaign
end
```

Here is the Campaign controller..

**controllers/campaigns_controller.rb**

```
class CampaignsController < ApplicationController
      def index
        @campaigns = Campaign.all.order("created_at DESC")
      end

      def new
        @campaign = Campaign.new
      end

      def create
        @campaign = Campaign.new(campaign_params)

        if @campaign.save
            flash[:success] = "Campaign Successfully Launched!"
            redirect_to @campaign
        else
            flash[:error] = "There was a problem launching your Campaign."
            redirect_to new_campaign_path
        end
      end

      def show
        @campaign = Campaign.find(params[:id])
      end

  private

      def campaign_params
        params.require(:campaign).permit(:name, :comment)
      end
end
```

My form looks like this...

**views/campaigns/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= form_for @campaign, url: {action: "create"} do |f| %>

    <%= f.label :name %>
    <%= f.text_field :name %>

    <%= f.label :comment %>
    <%= f.text_area :comment %>

        #....this is where I lose it..

    <%= f.label :data_file %>

<% end %>
```

How should I got about this? Is this a case use for collection_select? Any advice or even tutorial links will be highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to have `belongs_to :campaign` in upload model so that relation mapping are correct then you can move ahead with update process.

Comment: @AnantKolvankar - Thank you! I can't believe I didn't notice that. However, I'm still struggling with this.